# How to change the activity's layout after pressing the camera capture button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-camera, android-button

I'm writing a program that has an activity which uses the phone's camera to take a picture.
There is a capture button under the camera's SurfaceView. Now when the user presses the capture button,  I want the surface view to show a preview of the picture, and under this preview there should be two buttons (accept and cancel). If the user presses cancel, then the program should go back to the camera preview to take another picture.

I assume that I should define two layouts for this, but I don't know how to change from one layout to another within the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

1. Define your buttons within a `ViewGroup` i.e. `LinearLayout` with `visibility="gone"` within your layout.xml file. Then call `myButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` to make them visible. To hide them again, call `myButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);`.
2. Create your buttons programatically and attach them to the SurfaceView at runtime.

I'd prefer option 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two fragments for this.

The first fragment has a layout with the camera button.
The second fragment has the preview and the two buttons accept/cancel.

You can use the backstack so that cancel (or user pressing back) will take you back to the first fragment.

Here is code from the Fragments tutorial (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) showing how to replace a fragment with another

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

And your cancel button can pop fragments off the back stack, with popBackStack() (simulating a Back command by the user).

There is also another option. If you don't need a custom layout of the preview, you can skip using a custom camera and just open the camera as an intent using startActivityForResult. The intent will allow the user to take a photo (in which case it communicates the resulting photo with your main activity) , and also has a cancel button which returns to your app without taking a photo.